# SVG find orientation(angle) of a point to the x axis on a path

Tags: javascript, svg, css-transitions, raphael

I am making parallax by moving an object on a path and it is working fine with `getPointAtlength()` but I also need to rotate this object with the path.

I need something like `getPointAtLength()` but for angles that I get the angle of the point. Rapheal seems to have a method to it but it isn't friendly to svg elements that is created in html or I don't know how to deal with it. Any ideas?

```
var l = document.getElementById('path');
var element=$('#svg_26')
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var pathOffset=parseInt($('#l1').css('stroke-dashoffset'));
    var p = l.getPointAtLength(-1*pathOffset);
    translation = 'translate('+p.x+'px,'+p.y+'px)'
    $(element).css('transform',translation);
})
```

Comment: create fiddle, it will be helpful.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getPointAtLength in Raphael returns an object with attribute 'alpha'. Alpha is the angle that you need along the curve. In the example above it would be p.alpha

So you should be able to apply a rotation to the object rotated by p.alpha,

Eg..

myRaphElement.transform('t' + p.x + ',' + p.y + 'r' + p.alpha).

The last part will rotate the element around its center.

If you can't create the raph element itself as the svg is inline, I suspect you may be better off with a library like Snap.svg (which has mostly same commands as by same author), or you could possibly dynamically rotate by css transform using something like 'rotate('+l.alpha+','+l.x+','+l.y+')'

Edit: I misread as it had Raphael in the tags, when its not being used.

I personally would use Snap for this case, as Raphael doesn't add a lot here. You could possibly create a Raphael element off screen with the same path as the inline element just to use the angle, but feels like overkill to load a library for that.

In Snap you could access the element with..

```
myElement = Snap('#svg_26')
p = myElement.getPointAtLength(-1*pathOffset);    
myElement.transform('t' + p.x + ',' + p.y + 'r' + p.alpha)
```

Comment: but my elements arent raphael they r normal elements in SVG tag in html

Comment: tried Raphael.getPointAtLength(l,offset) but gave me NaNs

Comment: If you are purely using inline, then I think Raphael is the wrong tool for the job, try Snap.svg. Same answer would apply then as it works with inline svg.

Answer (score 19):

Using a library for this kind of task would be overkill. Its actually quite simple to write your own function to calculate the angle. All you have to do is use pointAtLength two time with a little offset:

```
var p1 = path.getPointAtLength(l)
var p2 = path.getPointAtLength(l + 3)
```

and then calculate the angle of the resulting line and the x-axis using Math.atan2

```
var deg = Math.atan2(p1.y - p2.y, p1.x - p2.x) * (180 / Math.PI);
```

here is a little example using the above formula

```js
var path = document.getElementById("path")
var obj = document.getElementById("obj")
var l = 0
var tl = path.getTotalLength()

function getPointAtLengthWithRotation(path, length) {
  var p1 = path.getPointAtLength(length)
  var p2 = path.getPointAtLength(length + 3)
  var deg = Math.atan2(p1.y - p2.y, p1.x - p2.x) * (180 / Math.PI);
  return {
    x: p1.x,
    y: p1.y,
    angle: deg
  }
}

setInterval(function() {
  l += 1
  if (l > tl) l = 0;
  var p = getPointAtLengthWithRotation(path, l)
  obj.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ") rotate(" + (p.angle + 180) + ")")
}, 30)
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200" height="200">
  <path id="path" d="M 81.713425,82.629068 C 77.692791,85.788547 73.298237,77.367896 68.194886,79.039107 63.091534,80.710434 58.027628,96.952068 53.04637,97.140958 48.065112,97.329732 50.503508,75.285207 45.397105,74.05952 40.290703,72.833834 38.487501,93.968537 33.85932,91.287114 29.23114,88.605807 32.245641,70.914733 29.647307,66.19971 27.048973,61.484686 19.604932,68.733636 17.542589,63.315055 15.480245,57.896474 32.172733,59.004979 32.053727,53.363216 31.93472,47.721442 8.0865997,39.989401 9.2246856,34.665848 10.362772,29.342295 28.830448,38.693055 31.065274,33.7132 33.300101,28.733334 22.734045,13.601966 26.210126,9.6067771 29.686208,5.6115765 41.809938,29.357138 46.524268,27.383715 c 4.71433,-1.973424 3.011846,-23.1001292 8.022646,-23.3332919 5.0108,-0.2331744 4.529056,18.3713929 9.45006,20.4259809 4.921003,2.054588 12.017373,-15.4803016 16.717604,-13.058602 4.700233,2.421699 -6.261038,14.180819 -2.913997,18.778859 3.347041,4.59804 12.339067,-3.78046 13.896719,1.543011 1.557652,5.323471 -9.713912,13.199372 -9.176986,18.679109 0.536926,5.479772 19.347976,2.957331 18.124596,8.213665 -1.223374,5.256392 -21.036293,1.236997 -24.253076,5.968111 -3.216785,4.731114 9.342224,14.869033 5.321591,18.028511 z"
  fill="none" stroke="grey" />
  <path id="obj" d="M-5 -5 L5 0L-5 5z" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

**<animateMotion rotate="auto" ... performs the guidance of automatically**

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 150 100" width="300" height="200">
  <path id="path" d="M 81.713425,82.629068 C 77.692791,85.788547 73.298237,77.367896 68.194886,79.039107 63.091534,80.710434 58.027628,96.952068 53.04637,97.140958 48.065112,97.329732 50.503508,75.285207 45.397105,74.05952 40.290703,72.833834 38.487501,93.968537 33.85932,91.287114 29.23114,88.605807 32.245641,70.914733 29.647307,66.19971 27.048973,61.484686 19.604932,68.733636 17.542589,63.315055 15.480245,57.896474 32.172733,59.004979 32.053727,53.363216 31.93472,47.721442 8.0865997,39.989401 9.2246856,34.665848 10.362772,29.342295 28.830448,38.693055 31.065274,33.7132 33.300101,28.733334 22.734045,13.601966 26.210126,9.6067771 29.686208,5.6115765 41.809938,29.357138 46.524268,27.383715 c 4.71433,-1.973424 3.011846,-23.1001292 8.022646,-23.3332919 5.0108,-0.2331744 4.529056,18.3713929 9.45006,20.4259809 4.921003,2.054588 12.017373,-15.4803016 16.717604,-13.058602 4.700233,2.421699 -6.261038,14.180819 -2.913997,18.778859 3.347041,4.59804 12.339067,-3.78046 13.896719,1.543011 1.557652,5.323471 -9.713912,13.199372 -9.176986,18.679109 0.536926,5.479772 19.347976,2.957331 18.124596,8.213665 -1.223374,5.256392 -21.036293,1.236997 -24.253076,5.968111 -3.216785,4.731114 9.342224,14.869033 5.321591,18.028511 z"
  fill="none" stroke="grey" />
  <polygon points="0,0 -5,-5 -5,5"  style="fill:green">
    <animateMotion begin="0s" dur="10s" rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite">
        <mpath xlink:href="#path"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
  </polygon>
</svg>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).